# QGIS crashes when downloading GPX files

Tags: qgis, gpx

I've been working on converting GPX files to GEOJSON and using them for analysis, so I make use of the QGIS plugin "GPS TOOLS". Thus far every time I attempt to download the files, the program crashes.

I've come to use GPS Babel as a workaround, but it would be nice to use this plugin as well...

[image: gps tools]

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: GPS Tools. Crashes it every time I try to import the GPX file.

Comment: Yeah, that plugin has never worked for me either. Good thing you don't need it!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a plugin to import GPX files. Just import them as you would any other vector file.

> Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer > Browse... > find the GPS unit and select your GPX files

[image]

This is with a Garmin etrex 20x. Depending on what brand/model of GPS unit you have, your file structure may vary.